# Should the tags [hierarchical] and [hierarchy] be merged?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

I just noted that both the [hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hierarchy) (1,699 tagged questions) and [hierarchical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hierarchical) (324 tagged questions) exist.

It seems like they are virtually identical.

Comment: They even share the same tag description.

Comment: It just doesn't matter, there is no expert in the hierarchy.  They are contextual tags at best, not very good ones.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, the tag is at best mediocre, there are probably better alternative tags for all the questions. Not that having the tag twice makes things any better...